# Configure newenvironment with xkeyval

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, xkeyval

I am having trouble getting xkeyval to work with \newenvironment. If I define the whole thing as a command instead, it works perfectly. So my guess is that the problem is not how I use xkeyval, but how I define the environment. 
I am having a hard time identifying the problem. TexStudio tells me that the error log is very big, so it is impossible to tell what is wrong by going through it.

```
\makeatletter

\define@cmdkey[m]{graph}{xmax}{}
\define@cmdkey[m]{graph}{xmin}{}
...
\define@cmdkey[m]{graph}{label}{}


\presetkeys[m]{graph}{
xmax=10,
xmin=0,
ymax=10,
ymin=0,
axis=middle,
ticks=none,
xlabel=x,
ylabel=y,
clip=individual,
domain=0:10.5,
xlabelpl=right,
ylabelpl=above,}{}

\newenvironment{graf}[1][]{ %
\setkeys[m]{graph}{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=\cmdm@graph@axis,
unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},font=\Large,\cmdm@graph@xlabelpl},
every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},font=\Large,\cmdm@graph@ylabelpl},
xlabel=$ \cmdm@graph@xlabel $,
ylabel=$ \cmdm@graph@ylabel $,
domain=\cmdm@graph@domain,
xmin=\cmdm@graph@xmin,
xmax=\cmdm@graph@xmax ,
ymin=\cmdm@graph@ymin,
ymax=\cmdm@graph@ymax ,
samples=100,
ticks=\cmdm@graph@ticks,
no marks,
clip mode=\cmdm@graph@clip,
]

}
{\end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}}


\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{graf}[1][]{}{}
```

generates the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \graf already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

You *really* don't want to ignore that error. Call your enviornment something else, otherwise you would be redefining `\endgraf` (which would be bad).